# Bathroom p-trap 2in male to 1 1/4 in drain outlet

Tags: drain, pvc, p-trap

I am trying to replace pipes and trap in my bathroom sink.

For some reason the drain is connected via a 2in male threaded pvc pipe.
On the other end I have a "standard" 1 1/4in metal pipe (non threaded).

How would you go about realizing a p-trap in this scenario ?

Hope the pic helps...
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get all these pieces and insure they fit, then cut off the stub out near the existing trap and glue on the slip joint fitting. The tubing from the trap might have to be cut off if it protrudes so far in that it hits the interior of the in wall tubing where itvturns.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a slip joint fitting glued to the stub out. It will be the correct size to receive the tubing from the trap and allow adjustment  both in-and-out and rotation. These adjustments along with swing of the trap in an arc allow alignment of all the joints.

These slip joint fittings come straight or with a bend. The one in the pic is a bend, but you use what is correct for your case. The one with the bend must be installed in a horizontal plane. Dry fit it and mark with a line indicating horizontal.  When it is glued on there is not much time to adjust.

[image: slip joint at stub-out]

Comment: so if I understand correctly I should cut the existing elbow , then glue a p-trap fitting like [this one](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-1-1-2-in-x-1-1-2-in-dia-PVC-Schedule-40-Hub-Trap-Adapter-Fitting/3132641?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-plb-_-google-_-lia-_-142-_-indoordrainage-_-3132641-_-0&placeholder=null&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAjwmqKJBhAWEiwAMvGt6Ff7hH5b1G8WJZfnt-SjSPQS9m3PHoTekTjf9PLGeCUwAg7dp2aKnhoCRYcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) and then get a new trap with the regular slip joint fitting. is that correct? if so, can I cut right above the old glued point? any other recommendation?

Comment: You might be able to use the proper size Fernco connector https://www.google.com/search?q=soft+rubber+drain+coupling&oq=soft+ru+ber+drain+coupling&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33i10i22i29i30.16612j1j8&client=tablet-android-samsung-nf-rev1&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8#oshopproduct=gid:167460585311170926,mid:576462671808596938,oid:770887558890921686,pvt:hg&oshop=apv

Comment: Great hint! This is after I cut the elbow in my drain, correct?

Comment: Using a soft rubber link would require you to cut the straight section next to the wall leaving enough pipe on each side of the cut for the rubber link to seal. This would allow you to shift the pipe toward the drain and rotate it as necessary. Get the right link (right length and of course diameter.